# Java LinkedHashSet loadFactor

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm curious as to the reasoning for the loadFactor in a LinkedHashSet. If my understanding of the Linked List Hash is correct, collisions are kept in a LL and increasing the loadFactor would just reduce the number of linked List nodes. Which I would assume would mean that your hash function isn't reducing the load on the set.

Thanks in advance for your expertise.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: The load factor has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the `Linked` part of `LinkedHashSet`.  _Nothing._  It only affects the expected length of the buckets, which are stored as a completely different linked list, not the same as the linked list that maintains entry order.

Answer (score 0):

Non-existant entries do not occupy link nodes.

The load factor only applies to the underlying `Object[]` array, but it will only store `null` in unoccupied slots, not link nodes.

Only occupied entries are linked (for rather obvious reasons).

It literally is a hash table, which stores *linked entry nodes*.

You need to look at the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regardless of how they are handled, collisions in a hashtable (such as HashSet and HashMap) are bad and should be avoided. Decreasing the load factor can reduce collisions at the cost of memory.
2. A linked list is the method used to mitigate collisions in plain old HashSet and HashMap in Java.
3. A LinkedHashSet (and LinkedHashMap) add an additional linked list over all elements/keys for faster and more consistent iteration. This linked list has nothing to do with the collision mitigation strategy; it is only used when iterating, especially useful with a sparse set/map.